# Symfony 4 - VichUploader can delete file?

Tags: file, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

in my Symfony 4 project, when an User upload a file, I would like replace the $user file attribute.

So I would like delete the previous file and replace it by the new.

I found this : https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/ed88af73ab04a5c4908baffad009bc1e47631a01/Storage/AbstractStorage.php#L84

The function :

```
public function remove($obj, PropertyMapping $mapping)
{
    $name = $mapping->getFileName($obj);
    // the non-strict comparison is done on purpose: we want to skip
    // null and empty filenames
    if (null == $name) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->doRemove($mapping, $mapping->getUploadDir($obj), $name);
}
```

But how can I use it in my service to replace files ?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the lifecycle events provided by Vich:

```
# config/packages/vich_uploader.yaml or app/config/config.yml
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/products
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/products'

            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

Note the **delete_on_update** & **delete_on_remove** parameters.

https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/usage.md#step-3-configure-the-lifecycle-events-optional-step