# VichUploaderBundle Removing an image asynchronously using message queue

Tags: symfony, asynchronous, vichuploaderbundle, liipimaginebundle

Would anyone be able to help me delete a file using VichUploaderBundle asynchronously?

The images are being uploaded to S3 and being cached by LiipImagineBUndle.
When I was deleting the enitity straight from the database the image would remove fine.

For performance I want to put the file deletion in a message queue.

The message queue is working fine as setup here: https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/events/howto/remove_files_asynchronously.md

The problem is a I don't know how to actually delete the original file. I don't quite understand what needs to be done below.

All that is returned from the message is the filename.

```
$filename = $message->getFilename();

// delete your file according to your mapping configuration
```

I have managed to delete the cache files fine but I cannot delete the orginal file.

```
namespace App\MessageHandler;

use App\Message\RemoveProductImageMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;
use Liip\ImagineBundle\Imagine\Cache\CacheManager;

class RemoveProductImageMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
    {
    
        private $cacheManager;
    
        public function __construct(CacheManager $cacheManager)
        {         
            $this->cacheManager = $cacheManager;
        }   
    
        public function __invoke(RemoveProductImageMessage $message): void
        {
            $filename = $message->getFilename();
    
            // delete your file according to your mapping configuration. What does this mean?
    
            // Need to delete original image here but don't understand how
            
            $this->cacheManager->remove($filename, 'large');
            $this->cacheManager->remove($filename, 'header');
            $this->cacheManager->remove($filename, 'medium');
            $this->cacheManager->remove($filename, 'profile');
            $this->cacheManager->remove($filename, 'thumb');                
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: The [Messenger Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) relies on 2 files, the message class that holds data (in your case this is just the filename) and the handler that does your action (in your case remove a file). The Github link you gave shows how these 2 files are setup with the 3rd file showing you how to dispatch that message (from the link it looks like it is via a *onPreRemove* event subscriber).

Comment: Thanks @bossman
It's the actual deletion of the orginal file though that is the problem. By this point the entity has been deleted and I can't seem to get the mapping for VichUploader to delete the file.

I've found this function, but don't know how to get the mapping.

use Vich\UploaderBundle\Storage\StorageInterface;
$this->StorageInterface->remove($obj, $propertyMapping);

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852581/symfony-4-vichuploader-can-delete-file) might help by setting the *delete_on_remove* property in the vich config? I havnt used vich bundle to be honest so not sure if that is still relivent but probably is for doctrine lifecycles.

Comment: Thank you, but I've got that and was working fine. That's the reason to remove it into the mesaage queue so it deletes it later on instead of instantly. Maybe i'm mis-understanding how this all works.

The reason for the change is when running an already large cron command to delete removed users info it may have to delete a load of images (and the various thumbnails) so i thought sending it to a queue might be more performant.
Also for when a user deletes it they won't have to wait so long.

Comment: It's definitely the way to do it, messenger is great for this. Also make sure you're consuming the messages with a worker etc.. Copy the Github example exactly, the dispatch method in the subscriber is getting the mapping.

Comment: Thanks for you help on this. It is much appreciated. The messenger queue is all set up fine and working, and is deleting the thumbnils through liipimgaine. It's how you delete a file in vichuploader with just the file name that i'm stumped on. It seems to either need an object or entity and the mapping.
I might post an issue on their github as the documentation isn't very clear how to do that.